# Pop up coding to avoid browser blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a need to use a lot of pop ups to provide greater detail into items users are interested in.

The problem is the percentage of time that a browser will block these pop ups.

I would need to find a way to do one or both of two things:

1. Find a way to show pop ups like with lightbox that will not be blocked by browsers without greatly hindering page load time
2. Provide a JavaScript / JQuery alert that can detect when a pop up has been blocked by a browser and notify a user through an alert along with a custom message written by me

Anyone familiar with some JavaScript coding that will do this or if lightbox is a practical solution without hindering page load time. There is likely to be anywhere from 10-30 different pop ups on a given page.

Comment: So, 10-30 more DIV? I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Well lets put it this way. If I went to your site and it told me to unblock pop ups so it would work. I'd leave, and never come back....

Answer (score 2):

Many sites that want to show "pop-up" info these days choose to just show an overlay div in the same browser window and do NOT open a separate window.  Using an overlay in the same window completely avoids pop-up blockers since no new window is being opened thus your content is never blocked.

Since pretty much all browsers come configured these days with some sort of default pop-up blocking, it is not going to work well for you to detect popup blocking and tell the user something.  At that point, your site just doesn't work with the default configuration of the user's browser and it's not going to be the right thing to try to get them to change the configuration of their browser.  Instead, you need to change how your site works to be compatible with pop-up blocking (probably by not using popup windows).